# Should bullets appear before animations, or animations before bullets?

Tags: presentation, curriculum

I'm designing curriculum that involves many steps and a correlating animation to go with it. The end goal of this curriculum will be to turn into a video where it might end up on Youtube (or something similar) for self-study.

Each animation has text that goes with it that describes it. My question is, **Between the Animation and the Text, what should appear first?** Please also include *why* you think it should go first.

I am not concerned on whether I should or shouldn't have animation or text. For the sake of this answer, both must be there.

To help frame the question, I created two simple slides/videos:

#### **A. Bullets before Animation**

[image]

#### **B. Animation before Bullets**

[image]

Which of these two options leads to better learning/retention? If one is better suited for video and self study, and the other is better suited for in-class live-teacher presentation, please let me know and why you think so.

Comment: Do an experiment to find out.  Personally, I would put the text first so it is easier to skip the animation.

Comment: My intuition would be text-first. Text should have priority, and visuals as a secondary support. E.g.: Usually titles go above an image. In law, the primary text has priority, and any supporting explanations are not legally binding.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I would do:

- I would move the ball first. Show them what is happening then use the text to support/explain it.
- Only change one thing on the slide at a time. There should be a delay between the ball moving and the bullet being added. Too many things moving is confusing. But one thing moving is a great way to guide someone's eyes to the important information.
- Possibly gray out the previous bullets. If you end up with a wall of text then it may be unnatural to dart your eyes from the very top (where the figure is) to the very bottom (where the new bullet is). Putting them side-by-side might help too.

Slide design is an art so don't feel compelled to follow any strict rules. Try it out and see how it works.

Answer (score 0):

You want to be understood. That means as little distractions as possible, i.e., no animations. No gimmicks.

Short, sweet, to the point.

The very best presentation I've ever seen was just images (photographs, cartoons, drawings of penguins). No text whatsoever. Strangely, the images were precisely on topic to what was being presented.

Comment: I'm afraid this doesn't really help my question. The actual presentation is going to be far more complicated than a ball moving in a square. Its going to be a lesson in Networking and how a packet moves across a network. I generally disagree with the thought that 'no animations is always best', there is a time and a place where they make the world of difference. For example, doing [this](http://www.practicalnetworking.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/packtrav-host-switch-host.gif) with static images is possible, but has a smaller retention for students. Animations work great when done right.

Comment: Then make a "slide" that is *only* the animation. Or break it down so you can e.g. repeat pieces if needed.

Comment: Which would work if it was in-person, live, with a teacher. But for the case of a video / recorded presentation, having both the bullet and the animation help. It gives student the visual representation of what is happening (animation), along with the 6-8 word bullet to explain it for their note taking. Again, this question is not about which ONE to use. But when using BOTH, which should come first?

Comment: If the ball is on top of the text, the ball should move first. Reading from top to down is something natural.

Comment: For lecture slides, having no text is often **horrible**. I've had too many classes where I go back and read the professor's slides but can't figure out any of the figures because they didn't add a few supporting words.